# How to get the below result using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've tried with the progress bars, but the issue I'm the remaining part of the progress bar.

[image: Wanted Result]

For example, if I gave a width on the progress bar, I'm getting the remaining percent as gray color

[image: Ending up with when using progress bars]

Answer (score 0):

Why not with some divs?

```css
.bars-container{
  margin:2em auto;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  position:relative;
}
.bars-container > div{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
.negative{
  right:50%;
}
.negative div{
    background:red;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;}
.positive{
  left:50%;
}
.positive div{
  background:green;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bars-container">
  <div class="negative"><div style="width:90%"></div></div>
  <div class="positive"><div style="width:5%"></div></div>
</div>
```